# How do you create a bare repo that becomes the source

Tags: git

i have struggled to implement git as my version control system on numerous occasions... so frustrated. read numerous articles and tutorials. searched but can't seem to create a search that addresses what i need to know. In this attempt i am trying to do the following. Tell me if this is wrong please.

1. MAIN BARE REPO: create a bare repository on my development machine that i can push changes to (done. currently has nothing in it.)
2. DEVELOPMENT BRANCH REPO: initiate a repository in the directory that i can make changes in and then push to the bare repository. (done. completed the first commit.)
3. PRODUCTION BRANCH REPO: initiate a repository on my host to pull updates from the bare repository. (not done yet.)

I thought that #1 and #2 were almost done when i attempted to push from DEVELOPMENT to MAIN BARE REPO and got:

```
no origin was found for working tree
```

Do i need to set the MAIN BARE REPO as the origin? Is there a command to do that? I'm afraid to ask for an article because most of the material that is written on git i have a really hard time applying for some reason.

If the answer is:

```
git push --all <url-of-bare-repo>
```

What does that look like with the following information?

1. The development branch that i'm pushing from is located at /Users/me/sites/devel_repo
2. The main bare repo that i'm pushing to is located at /Users/me/sites/main_repo

Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see the point of the main (bare) repository in your setup. It seems more efficient to just push from the development repository directly to the production repository.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky, i agree in principle. But everything i've read says don't push anywhere but to a bare repository.

Comment: Well, now you're reading something that says it's fine to push to a non-bare repository as long as you're careful ;-) I do it all the time, actually. The only catch is that if you're going to be pushing to the checked-out branch (as you would be, in this case), you have to set the `receive.denycurrentbranch` property in the repo configuration (or use a detached work tree) and create a hook script to run `git checkout -f` every time you push to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`origin` is a remote.

You can add it like this from your DEV repo:

```
git remote add origin path/to/bare/repo
```

So in your case, it will be like:

```
git remote add origin /Users/me/sites/main_repo
```

Once this is done, you can issue the `git push origin master` etc.

Generally, when you clone from another repo, this `origin` is automatically setup. It is just a convention and a default. You can have some other name if you like.

Also, note that, to push, it is **not necessary to have a remote**. It is just a short-hand to a repo path / url so that you don't have to repeat it again and again. It looked for origin when you pushed because when you do `git push`, it by default tries to push to origin.